# Bind Entry TextChanged to the CanExecute method of button command in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.forms

I want to disable the send button if any of the three entries is empty, but how that can be achieved in an MVVM fashion?

I thought of the CanExecute delegate, but how can I fire it whenever the TextChanged fired?

Also if I opt in the behaviors, how can I communicate with other controls like button if I'm using `Behavior<Entry>`

This is the view:

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <AbsoluteLayout>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="20"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="56"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="10"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Label Text="Contact Us" FontSize="Medium" Grid.ColumnSpan="3"/>
            <Entry Text="{Binding ContactData.message_name}" x:Name="subject" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Placeholder="Subject"/>
            <Entry Keyboard="Email" Text="{Binding ContactData.receiver_email}" x:Name="email" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Placeholder="Email"/>
            <Editor Text="{Binding ContactData.message_subject}" x:Name="body" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1" />

            <Button Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="1" Command="{Binding ContactFormSent}" Text="Send"/>
        </Grid>
    </AbsoluteLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

in the ViewModel:

```
public ContactViewModel()
{
    ContactFormSent = new RelayCommand(SendContactInfo);
    ContactData = new ContactModel();
}

private bool CanSend() //this only get called when the view model is constructed
{
    return !(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ContactData.receiver_email) && string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ContactData.message_subject) &&
        string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ContactData.message_name));
}
```

In the Behavior option, I wan it to be used with both `Entry` and `Editor`, so is my way to go is the `Behavior` class, not the generic version? if so, then how can I implement it?

Comment: Could you call CanSend() in the OnTextChanged event for all of the entries?

Comment: You can add a bool in the view model and bind the button's IsEnabled property to that bool and update it from CanSend()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually, in order to react to a view event using MVVM pattern, it is recommended that you use [EventToCommandBehaviour](https://blog.xamarin.com/turn-events-into-commands-with-behaviors/).

But in this case it is not needed, as the setters on properties bound to `Entry` should trigger every time text changes. You can use that to trigger `ChangeCanExecute()` on command to notify view that the button can now be enabled/disabled.

For e.g.:

```
string _firstName;
public string FirstName
{
    get { return _firstName; }
    set
    {
        if (_firstName != value)
            SendCommand.ChangeCanExecute();
        SetProperty(ref _firstName, value, nameof(FirstName));
    }
}

string _lastName;
public string LastName
{
    get { return _lastName; }
    set
    {
        if (_lastName != value)
            SendCommand.ChangeCanExecute();
        SetProperty(ref _lastName, value, nameof(LastName));
    }
}

string _email;
public string Email
{
    get { return _email; }
    set
    {
        if (_email != value)
            SendCommand.ChangeCanExecute();
        SetProperty(ref _email, value, nameof(Email));
    }
}

Command _sendCommand;
public Command SendCommand 
{
    get
    {
        return _sendCommand ?? (_sendCommand = new Command(OnSend, CanSend));
    }    
}

bool CanSend(object obj)
{
    return Validate();
}

void OnSend(object obj)
{
    if(Validate())
    {
        //actual button click execution
    }
}

bool Validate()
{
    // disable button if any entry empty
    return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(_firstName)
                  && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(_lastName)
                  && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(_email);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`Command` has a public method [`ChangeCanExecute()`](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.Command/).
When you new a `Command`, you could specify the `canExecute` condition. Once your `TextChanged` event is triggered, call the `ChangeCanExecute()` method.

Example:

```
Command someCommand = new Command(
 () => SomeMethod(),
 ()=> { return CanSend(); }
);
```

Once a `Button` changed a text:

```
private void TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ViewModel.someCommand.ChangeCanExecute();
}
```